# If Maverick Meerkat is 70, what is Utopic Unicorn?

Tags: 14.10, android, udev

I was reading [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions) on solving some problems one might encounter when using an Android device for development.

The solution is to create a file as follows:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/##-android.rules
```

> In the above file replace ## with the number 50 if you are running
>   Gusty/Hardy/Dapper (50-android.rules) or with the number 70 if you are
>   running Karmic Koala/Lucid Lynx/Maverick Meerkat(70-android.rules)

I am currently on Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn and I have a few questions:

1. What is this number? Where do I find mine?
2. The [official Android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) don't state that this number is version specific. They just use `51`. Is it not version-dependent?
3. If I ever upgrade my Ubuntu version, will I have to recreate this file with a newer number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one data point for you:

I use 51-android.rules on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system and it works great.

I got this from the instructions on some blog post long ago when trying to connect to my tablet using adb (I succeeded).  In other words, I do not know the provenance of the answer, but I can verify that it works.

I can't see that it will hurt to try one, or any, and see if they work.  My guess is that it simply controls the order in which the rules are processed.

I could never get the thing to connect on Windows.  That was another increment of force that eventually shoved me over to Linux.